# Exact Code segment size for a windows process

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

The linux file proc/{pid}/status as we know gives us some fine grain memory footprint for a particular process. One of the parameters thrown by it is the 'VmExe' or the size of the text segment of the process. I'm particularly interested in this field but am stuck in a windows environment with no proc file system to help me. cygwin mimics most of the procfs but the {pid}/* files seem to be one of those parts which cygwin ignores. I tried playing around with the VmMap tool on windows sysinternals, but the closest field I got was was 'Private Data Size' on a Private working set. I'm not really sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know if Windows tracks that information, it doesn't seem that it would be very useful.  FWIW, you can use EnumProcessModulesEx to list the modules loaded into the process and/or VirtualQueryEx to examine the process memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [vmmap.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) from sysinternals, and see if it displays the information you are looking for, for a given process. If the information you are seeking is displayed there, you could take a look at the api calls the application uses, or ask on the sysinternals forums on msdn. I know this isnt exactly what you were looking for in an answer, but it hopefully points you in the right direction.

If you are talking about the :text segment in the PE itself, you can get that information from the debughlp library, and a number of other ways (there are a few libraries floating around for binary analysis).